# Reading gpkg format in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, geopandas

i'm not able to read gpkg ( 90GB ) file in spark the only solution i found is to 
convert it into csv and convert it back to Geospatial using GeoSpark in Scala

```
import geopandas as gdp

tiles = gdp.read_file('tile.gpkg')
tiles.to_csv('tiles.csv')
```

and this only works for sample data and i'm not able to do it for the full data 90GB

how is it possible to read gpkg file format in GeoSpark ?